# I want to update datetime downward till the next date with conditions from other tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have made all necessary data on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d78621730f29ae59e26da395b28f3771) there are three tables `EMPLOYEES` with column name

- EMPLOYEE_ID1
- WEEKREST

2nd table named as `JOB_ROSTER` with column name as

- employee_id
- WEEK_START
- DEP_ID
- SHIFT_ID

3rd one is `PAY_IN_OUT` which have column named as

- EMP_CODE
- DATE_IN

what I want is I want to select employee_id1 and Weekrest from employees and checks shift from job_roster check dates and update employee 1000010 from `pay_in_out` in column date_in   for shift A like `01-01-2021 06:01:10 AM` for shift B like `01-01-2021 02:01:10 pm` for shift c like `10-01-2021 06:01:10 pm`.

in `job_roster` there employee id 1000010 not exists there only three employees like  1000011, 1000012, 1000013 it checks where its shifts come in date between roaster date and checks till the next date of `job_roster`, mean shift starts from 03-JAN-21 it goes through all dates till next date agt that employee comes like in dbfiddle `job_roster` have first 03-JAN-21 than 17-jan-21 it checks shifts and than date in `job_roster` and also week rest from employees and than paste datetime in `pay_in_out` where employee =1000010
what I am trying is like this

```
DECLARE  
   EMP_id EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID1%TYPE;  
   EMP_REST EMPLOYEES.WEEK_REST%TYPE;

   CURSOR C_EMP is  
      SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID1, WEEK_REST FROM EMPLOYEES 
      WHERE SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX = 103001;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN C_EMP;  
   LOOP  
      FETCH C_EMP into EMP_id, EMP_REST ;
      UPDATE PAY_IN_OUT
  SET DATE_IN = TO_DATE('01-01-2021 02:10:01 AM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS AM')
WHERE 
 EMP_CODE = 1000010 
    AND ATT_DATE IN (SELECT WEEKSTART FROM job_roster where shift_id = 'A')
    AND TO_CHAR( ATT_DATE, 'D' )=EMP_REST;  
    EXIT WHEN C_EMP%notfound;      
END LOOP;  
CLOSE C_EMP;  
END;
```

Comment: is there anyone who can answer this?????

Comment: If you want an answer then you need to provide the following: Expected output - as formatted text, if your table is to be updated show the expected updated values. Provide a procedure/anonymous block that actually complies. Yours has several syntax errors. If that is your problem then that should be the question. See revised [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a346724e2f05e3a43d2a2cc822f8a72).

Comment: @Belayer yes that is not working and not accurate but need to updates like mentioned don't know how to do this

Comment: Point is you need to at least provide a compile-able block and explain why the results are wrong. It is understood that it is "not working and not accurate", but with compile errors it is also  not run-able. Further you need show, as formatted test, what results you want.

Comment: @Belayer Honestly if this all is not explanatory than Please tell me how can I explain it I tried each and every thing to explain on every where on question on `dbfiddle` also

Comment: First, could you update the grammar to not be a large run-on sentence, for example use periods? I think you're also safe to remove a bit of wording because some of it sounds a bit repetitive. Second is `ATT_DATE` supposed to be the date you're wanting to insert for each shift/week start for emp 1000010? If so, you're going to need to define it at least in the `DECLARE` section; otherwise it'll need to be updated somehow.